# CASE in sql server -implementation Clarification?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, case

I have this simple table in sql server :

```
DECLARE @tbl table( a int ,  b NVARCHAR(100), isCalcByA bit)

INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT 1,'c',1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'d',0
```

Ok.

If I run this :

```
SELECT CASE 
            WHEN  isCalcByA = 1 THEN  a
            ELSE  b
       END  FROM @tbl
```

It yields an error :

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>    Conversion failed when converting  the nvarchar value 'd' to data type int.

I **can understand** why it is happening  :

Because the data which is being accumulated  (to be displayed) can't attach both  `int` and `string` at the same column .

Ok

But what about this :

```
SELECT 'dummy'
FROM   @tbl
WHERE  CASE 
            WHEN isCalcByA = 1 THEN a
            ELSE b
       END IS NOT NULL
```

**Here -**

- I *always* display `string`
- I don't accumulate different *displaying* results of  different types.
- I'm checking them against `not null` rather than a `string` or `int` value.

But still I get the *same* error .

What am I missing ?

**NB**

I know I can/should do this :

```
SELECT 'dummy'
FROM   @tbl
WHERE 
(isCalcByA = 1 AND a IS NOT NULL)

OR

(isCalcByA <> 1 AND b IS NOT NULL)
```

(which works fine)

But I'm asking why it is not working in the first `CASE` situation

Comment: `CASE WHEN isCalcByA = 1 THEN a ELSE b END IS NOT NULL` will never be false - the case statement can't return null.

Comment: @Bridge "never be false" is not a reason for error. it's like `where 1=2` ( which certainly not an error)

Comment: I agree - just saying that the where clause is pointless, as it will always be the same value, true.

Comment: @Bridge ok I get you - it was just a code to move it from a select ( which will finally crate a column) to another location. still i dont understand why the error

Comment: The possible results returned by the case statement must always be the same datatype - try casting `a` as varchar in the case statement and I suspect it'll do what you want.

Comment: @Bridge cast is a solution. Im looking for explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CASE` is an *expression* - it returns a *value* of a *specific* type. All possible values it might return must all be convertible to some common type. The system uses the type precedences rules to consider the types of all possible return values and decide what that common type is. `int` has higher precedence and wins.

```
CASE 
        WHEN isCalcByA = 1 THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(100),a)
        ELSE b
   END
```

would work because now the common type selected is unambiguously `nvarchar(100)`.

Comment: interesting.... but what do you mean by _int has higher precedence_ ? can you supply small sample please ? (which will work in X and not work with Y) ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - [Data Type Precedence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx): "When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher precedence"

Comment: so the sql engine walks through(runtime) all the different types of the relative columns and take the one with the higher priority and tries (**when? at what stage ? does it mean that it first scan all rows and then decides ?**) to convert them all the highest precedense value ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - each expression in a `THEN` clause (and `ELSE`) has a well defined type. It considers all of the `THEN` clause expression types, and decides on the overall type for the `CASE` expression. You might then consider that it re-writes the case as `CASE WHEN A THEN CONVERT(besttype,expression1) WHEN B THEN CONVERT(besttype,expression2) ELSE CONVERT(besttype,expression3) END` - of course, some of those conversions may never be actually attempted if their conditions are never true (as in your `1=1` example in a comment to ypercube's answer)

Answer (score 1):

No matter if you use `CASE` in the `SELECT` or the `WHERE` clause. `CASE` expressions should return the same datatype always. So, convert both columns to a datatype that can hold both:

```
CASE 
    WHEN isCalcByA = 1 THEN CAST(a AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ELSE b
END
```

From the [`CASE` expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) documentation:

> Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression.

When the various `WHEN` and the `ELSE` part have different datatypes as results, the highest precedence is chosen from this list: [Data Type Precedence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) and all results are converted to that datatype.

Your queries fail because `int` has higher precedence than `nvarchar`.

Comment: `SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 1 ELSE 'f' end` --works and it is not of the same type

Comment: @RoyiNamir - true, but if 1=1 ever turns out to be false, it will still *attempt* to convert `'f'` to an `int` and fail. Do you expect it to insert special case handling for a literal string that can never be converted versus the more usual usage where the string may be varying on each row and may indeed be convertible?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tbl table( a int ,  b NVARCHAR(100), isCalcByA bit)

INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT 1,'c',1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'d',0
UNION ALL
SELECT null,'d',1


SELECT CASE 
            WHEN  isCalcByA = 1 THEN  CAST(a AS VARCHAR(30))
            ELSE  b
       END  FROM @tbl
```

Above, you are selecting two different data types based on the select.

```
SELECT 'dummy'
FROM   @tbl
WHERE  CASE 
            WHEN isCalcByA = 1 THEN CAST(a AS VARCHAR(30))
            ELSE b
       END IS NOT NULL
```

Above, you are **selecting** 'dummy' every time, regardless of condition.

So, in the first statement, you are setting the `return type` based on the `case` and the case can return `two different types`.  In the second query, the return type is always the `same type`.

Comment: I dont know how well  you read my question - by the second code of yours also fails.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, I was just looking at what you were selecting...should have paid more attention.  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think about `CASE` like it is built-in `IF` from regular language. It's more like `... ? ... : ...` operator with strong typing - it has to result in a specific singular type. If you want to mix columns you need to cast it to for example nvarchar.

You can also think about it like the result of SELECT should be possible to be defined by `CREATE TABLE`.